# Could not get any response in Postman

Tags: api, web

**I get this error when I try my URL in Postman . I don't know where is the problem exactly.**

getBook(bookName): this method returns the book by that name

this how I post the URL in Postman

https://localhost:32244/api/books?name=Specification by Example

**app class**

```
route.get('/api/books?name=bookName',async (req , res) =>{


    const book= repoacc.getBook(req.params.bookName)

    res.send(book)

})
```

**route class**

```
const express = require('express')
const route = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const repoacc = require('./repositories/BookRepo.js')


route.get('/', (req , res) =>{

    res.send("welcome")

})


    route.get('/api/books/:bookName',async (req , res) =>{


        const book= repoacc.getBook(req.params.bookName)

        res.send(book)

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

In **app class** you must define route parameter `bookName` correctly:

```
route.get('/api/books?name=:bookName',async (req , res) => {
    const book = repoacc.getBook(req.params.bookName);
    res.send(book);
});
```

See [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params)